# liquibase data export crash with GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: sql-server, sybase, liquibase

I would like to use liquibase to export data (like portable csv flat files) connecting to different large database (sybase or sqlserver DB)
The DB could store more than 100 tables and 10GB

I found command:

```
liquibase --defaultsFile=/db/liquibase/db.properties --changeLogFile=/db/liquibase/data.xml --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog
```

Result:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I increased java memory to 32GB and still crashing
I tested on a small database with 1 small table. Export was ok

Do we have limitations with liquibase export data?
Do not want to manage diff data. Just want to export data current state.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please provide the content of the parameter files you are using?

Comment: If would be easier if others could reproduce this situation in their environment

Comment: Yes of course db.properties file used: 
 driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver classpath: /opt/jdbc/jtds-1.3.1.jar
 url: jdbc:jtds:sybase://XXX:6000;DatabaseName=XXX
 username: XXX
 password: XXX

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue using export directory. Documentation is not updated but I used dataOutputDirectory parameter to generateChangeLog option.
Without this parameter liquibase try to export in the changelog xml file.

Comment: if you could explain what changes you made, it would helpful to others(since you said `Documentation is not updated` )

Comment: Using `dataOutputDirctory` worked for me as well. In this case what happens is that data is written to csv files and changelog just points to these files and load data from these csv'. So ofcourse loading a lot of data in memory is not required and things go smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Jailer Tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jailer) to export data in liquibase format.